# In MySQL, does LONGTEXT waste space when only TEXT is necessary?

Tags: mysql, optimization, sqldatatypes

I have a column, its datatype is `LONGTEXT`. While `TEXT` datatype is enough for 95% of the values. I need `LONGTEXT` just for 5% of values.

Now I want to know, storing a small value in the `LONGTEXT` will waste a lot of space? Is that optimize?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lets look at MySQL documentation.

> TEXT[(M)] [CHARACTER SET charset_name] [COLLATE collation_name]
>
> A TEXT column with a maximum length of 65,535 (2^16 − 1) characters.
>   The effective maximum length is less if the value contains multibyte
>   characters. Each TEXT value is stored using a 2-byte length prefix
>   that indicates the number of bytes in the value.
>
> LONGTEXT [CHARACTER SET charset_name] [COLLATE collation_name]
>
> A TEXT column with a maximum length of 4,294,967,295 or 4GB (2^32 − 1)
>   characters. The effective maximum length is less if the value contains
>   multibyte characters. The effective maximum length of LONGTEXT columns
>   also depends on the configured maximum packet size in the
>   client/server protocol and available memory. Each LONGTEXT value is
>   stored using a 4-byte length prefix that indicates the number of bytes
>   in the value.
>
> MEDIUMTEXT [CHARACTER SET charset_name] [COLLATE collation_name]
>
> A TEXT column with a maximum length of 16,777,215 (2^24 − 1)
>   characters. The effective maximum length is less if the value contains
>   multibyte characters. Each MEDIUMTEXT value is stored using a 3-byte
>   length prefix that indicates the number of bytes in the value.

So the difference is 2 bytes for prefix.

Comment: Thank you. +1 Just can you please tell me how many difference is between `MEDIUMTEXT` and `TEXT` ?

Comment: as per the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-type-overview.html), MEDIUMTEXT has a 3-byte prefix.

Comment: @ESG I see. So what is your opinion about my case? Do you think using `LONGTEXT` for just 5% of values *(95% of values need `TEXT`)* is a good thing or bad?

Comment: @Alex Well, it depends on the number of rows. You're talking about 1 or 2 bytes different per row here. It most cases, it's an non-issue, and probably a much better option over trying to split long values into a different column/table.

Comment: I would use `MEDIUMTEXT`.  If I encounter something to big for that I will have other problems (packet size, etc).